# Why are columns in a GeoDataFrame supposedly 'missing" when the set_index method is called?

Tags: python, geopandas, pandas, graph

I am trying to use the NetworkX package in Python to find the shortest route between two points along a road network. Rather than straight lines between nodes in the road network, I need my script to return the actual geometries of the road network, as described in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62001044/shortest-route-when-converted-to-linestring-misses-the-path-in-osmnx). However, the following code, `edges = edges.set_index(['u', 'v', 'key'])`, results in this error:

```
        raise KeyError(f"None of (missing) are in the columns")
KeyError" "None of ['u', 'v', 'key'] are in the columns"
```

Meanwhile, the columns in my `edges` GeoDataFrame look like this:
[image]

Why are the `u`, `v`, and `key` columns "missing", and how do I fix this?

Comment: You don't have any 'u', 'v' or 'key' columns in your dataframe. You already have a ['u', 'v', 'key'] [`MultiIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.html)

Comment: Thank you! In other words, in my code, I can skip the line where the set_index() method is called.

Answer (score 3):

If one looks more closely, 'u', 'v', and 'key' aren't column names in my GeoDataFrame. They are not on the same line. They are, in fact, already the index I wanted to set.